# The server quit without updating PID file - Ubuntu 12.04 Server

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-12.04, mysql-5.6

I following this link to upgrade my mysql, `https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/mysql/mysql-5-6-ubuntu-12-04/`

The article ubuntu is x64, But my ubuntu is x32, So I change the download link to `http://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/MySQL-5.6/mysql-5.6.16-debian6.0-i686.deb`

When I finish install, When I type this following command to start mysql: `$ service mysql.server start`

It alert me :

```
Starting MySQL
. * The server quit without updating PID file (/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid).
```

When I try to type `service mysql-server restart`, It alert me a little deferent :

```
 * MySQL server PID file could not be found!
Starting MySQL
. * The server quit without updating PID file (/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid).
```

There is something maybe help:

- my.cnf is location at /etc/mysql/my.cnf
- `ps aux | grep mysql` will show different PID when type `ps aux | grep mysql` again

my.cnf file has the following line

```
# This will be passed to all mysql clients
# It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with ticks/quotes
# escpecially if they contain "#" chars...
# Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.
[client]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

# This was formally known as [safe_mysqld]. Both versions are currently parsed.
[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a new file inside the folder "/var/run/mysqld/" called "mysqld.pid"
then edit that file, set line 1 to: 1329 for example then start the server again

Answer (score 0):

Delete all existing pid file by command rm -f 'filename.pid'

And then start the server..

Thanks

Comment: Can you please be more specific on the filename.pid? I tried mysqld.pid and it doesn't work. still getting the same error

Comment: Search for the mysqld.pid in your server and delete the file manually.